# Publishing of workflow with a email step in CRM 4.0 rollup 6 fails

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

The error message is:

```
"An error occurred when the workflow was being created. Try to save the workflow again."
```

More info:
Running CRM 4.0, with service pack 6 installed.  I was able to publish workflows, but the moment I placed a email step on the workflow it did not want to publish, with the above error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this very 
[usefull post](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/e0a8b1f3-5bbf-4040-ab5c-2a67df362b5b)

In there they pointed to add the following lines to the web.config

`<authorizedType Assembly="mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" Namespace="System.Globalization" TypeName="CultureInfo" Authorized="True"/>`

That fixed my problem, and I am now happily publishing workflow rules.